# Scrapy Xpath unable to get all prices

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl [this page](https://www.tesco.com/direct/tv-offer.event?icid=offers_trade_slot1)

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tesco"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.tesco.com/direct/tv-offer.event?icid=offers_trade_slot1',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"product-tile")]'):
            learningscrapyItem = crawlerItem()
            learningscrapyItem['title'] = quote.xpath('.//h3/a/text()').extract_first()
            price = quote.xpath('.//div[@class="buy-box-container"]/p[2]/text()').extract_first()
            learningscrapyItem['price'] = price.strip()
            yield (learningscrapyItem)
```

I am having issues with the price xpath which is only pulling some prices:

```
//div[@class="buy-box-container"]/p[2]/text()
```

By removing text() I think I can see the reason why, the ones that are pulling the price though are setup like the below:

```
<p class="price">
£189.00
</p>
```

The ones that are not are structured like:

```
<p class="price">

<span class="from">From</span>
£549.00
</p>
```

So the strip() appears to be removing these. Is there a way with Xpath that I can get the text from within the paragraph tag and not from/or the span within it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `/text()` would only match the *direct text child node* and, you understood correctly, that the second example breaks the selector.

I would just get all the "text" nodes from inside the "price" element and grab the amount with `.re_first()`:

```
price = quote.xpath('.//div[@class="buy-box-container"]/p[2]//text()').re_first(r"\d+\.\d+")
```

Or, even simpler with a CSS selector instead of the XPath:

```
price = quote.css('.buy-box-container .price').re_first(r"\d+\.\d+")
```

Comment: you're a hero. I have just read the documentation on re_first as i wasn't aware of that. But could you explain what r"\d+\.\d+" is doing? Thanks a ton!

Comment: @FionaStone sure, it's just a *regular expression* that would match one or more digits followed by a literal dot followed by one or more digits. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below way to get the prices you wish to have.

Instead of using this:

`quote.xpath('.//div[@class="buy-box-container"]/p[2]/text()').extract_first()`

Try using this:

`quote.xpath('.//div[@class="buy-box-container"]//p[@class="price"]/text()').extract()[-1]`